# How to handle / create disaster backups for an ubuntu 18.04 server that can boot on any / most hardware

Tags: 18.04, server, backup, virtualization, headless

I'm currently running 4 different Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 servers for Apache and Bind. I got my configuration backup done by a script I wrote myself, making sure I got my MySQL databases, apache files and all config files from /etc /var/bind stored on an external backup.

So in case of a disaster I can restore all files and configurations of the servers (but have to do some manual labour for that).

So here is my question: What is the "usual" way for disaster backup of such a system. I tried clonezilla but I could not make it work on other hardware than the original one. But I'm sure this is can be done and is just a lack of knowledge problem.

I'm just wondering if there would be any better solutions for this problem.

I started looking into virtualizing but this seems to be overly complicated on a headless system.

As I'm feeling kinda lost atm I thought I'd ask for some directions or ideas.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many, many possible ways.

My own method is to break it down into three steps:

1. Clean-install Ubuntu (this does not need to be backed up).
2. Re-install additional applications, services, and customizations. I don't back these up -- I keep notes detailing step-by-step how to do it. The notes are handy for maintenance, troubleshooting, and other needs.

   - My own notes are in the format of a heavily-commented script. It's clear what each step does, why, and often includes a reference link. Six months from now, I won't recall each step, hence the comments.
   - Your own notes should be in a format that you easily understand. These are handy notes, not tedious homework.
   - It's important that your notes can be easily accessed in an emergency, or they're worthless. If you use an online Password Manager (you should), it's a convenient place to safely store these vital notes. On a bad day, you can simply read your notes on your phone.
3. Finally, restore data from a backup. There are many great tools for this easy step. Honestly, you could simply mount your backup and copy the data across.

   - How convenient that you have instructions on how to restore data...in your notes.

Using this method takes me about 60 minutes to completely rebuild and restore one of my average systems from bare metal. Step 1 takes about 30 minutes, Step 2 takes about 15 minutes (in a worst case scenario: Keyed manually reading notes from my phone), and Step 3 takes about 15 minutes. Your mileage may vary, of course.

The biggest benefit that I get from my method isn't listed. It's *maintainability*. I find that many weird issues are answered in my notes (or their reference links). Especially cryptic issues that appear after release-upgrades. Being confident that you can fully tear out Customization C, because now it's a baked-in feature, without damage, without the need to rebuild, is wonderful.

---

**Optional** If you have a lot of customizations, service files, cron jobs, etc. (not applications or packages) scattered across the system, then consider hardlinking each custom file to  a "customizations" directory in your /home or /var dir.

- Each customization gets backed up with your data, rather than you mucking about backing up a dozen different locations.
- The contents of the dir provide a handy checklist of what you must restore.
- Add the instructions on how to restore each to your notes. For example, you might need to restart services to re-read changed configs.

Comment: +1 from me :) I would script those notes (script with `apt purge {packages` and `apt install `packages}` , I try to stay away from sed instructions so I also use backup files on my personal partition for things like the config files for apache and sites-enabled/ or mysqls my.cnf. Those I copy onto the system disk after install.

Comment: Well, these are more or less the steps I take right now to reinstall a system, but not to the point where I scripted the installation of additional packages or configurations. I probably was hoping for a more "backup and restore" like approach, but I could of course just minimize the time it takes to recreate the whole configuration.

Comment: A few common problems that folks run into with "backup and restore" solutions: 1) They forget *how to restore*, the application name, the steps. 2) They forget their password to wherever-the-backup-is-stored. 3) Something changed over time, and the restore results in a broken system. There are super-simple clone-to-a-bootable-system  solutions, too. Commonly folks forget what they installed or customized, so when their system changes after a release-upgrade, something breaks that they cannot recall how to repair...so they wind up rebuilding. Note the common themes.

Comment: @user535733 I see the themes, but in all the cases it's just a question of documentation. I'm going for a non-headless system first and check out the vm options in such an environment but I guess I'll have to create setup scripts for all my servers anyway. Thanks for the hints.